# How do I create a conda envirionment with a specifed python version?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I want to create an environment with python version 3.6.

I was following this: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html

When I do `conda search python` I see all the versions including 3.6

But, when I do `conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda` it takes forever to run so I ended up interrupting.

When I do `conda create -n py36 python=3.6` and then check the version(after activating the environment), it is 2.7.16.
The problem is not specific to trying to create an environment with 3.6 but any version. They all end up being 2.7.16

Comment: did you activate the environment before checking the version?  conda activate (your_env )

Comment: Yep I did activate the environment before checking the version. It still shows 2.7.16

Comment: Can you also add the traceback after executing conda create. eg: Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done

Comment: Assuming you are on Windows, what is the output from `where python`, before and after you do `conda activate py36`?

Comment: Check how your PATH is changing, before and after activation. Add results to question.

Answer (score 1):

Creating env :  `conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda`

Activating your env: `conda activate py36`

Checking your version inside your env: `python --version`

EDIT:

To check all envs created by conda: `conda env list`

Your global python version might be 2.7.16.